# Error: ‘board’ was not declared in this scope (C++)

Tags: c++

I am writing code for a board game and trying to test it out.

I cannot figure out how to solve this error that gives the message:

> error: ‘board’ was not declared in this scope".

This message comes up for line 9. I would really appreciate the help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Board.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Board B;
    B.Player1(*board[15][15], B.pathP1[57]);
    B.printBoard();
}

void Board::Player1(char *board[15][15], char pathP1[57])
{
```

Board.h is below

```
#ifndef BOARD_H
#define BOARD_H

struct Board
{
  //Board board();
  char *board[15][15];
  char pathP1[57];
  
  void Player1(char *board[15][15], char pathP1[57]);
  void printBoard();
};
#endif //BOARD_H
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. It has to include the header of course. Also, "line 9" is not a helpful reference. Please use a comment to identify it `/* error here */`.

Comment: Please post Board.h as well!

Comment: I think you need to read a bit more about variables, scope, arrays, classes, and member variables in your favourite C++ book.

Comment: At the very least need to see the contents of `board.h`. It's looks like you have the common newbie confusions about how to pass arrays to functions. Plus the common newbie misunderstandings about how objects work.

Comment: It probably complains about this here: "*board[15][15]". I am not a compiler, but where is this variable declared?

Comment: If `board` and `pathP1` are members of your `Board` class then you **don't need** to pass them to your `Player1` method. Because `Player1` is a member function of your `Board` class it already has access to the member variables like `board` and `pathP1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have a misunderstanding about how objects work. There is no need to pass member variables to a member function because member functions have access to member variables **automatically**. That is one of the major features of object orientated programming (in C++ at least).

Rewrite your code like this

```
struct Board
{
  //Board board();
  char *board[15][15];
  char pathP1[57];
  
  void Player1();
  void printBoard();
};

int main()
{
    Board B;
    B.Player1();
    B.printBoard();
}

void Board::Player1()
{
    // do something with board and pathP1
    ...
}
```

In addition you need to revise how arrays and functions work. Although you don't need to pass the `board` and `pathP1` arrays to the `Player1` method the way you were trying to do it was also incorrect.

Comment: Thank you I really appreciate the help. I am still working on my programming and it seems that I still have a bit farther to go.